# Python Tkinter Treeview displaying mysql

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have a treeview in python tkinter and It displays in the screen. The only problem is that how can I make the first column to output 'available' if quantity is more than zero or 'out of stock' if the quantity of the item is zero and the query from database should start in the second column as 1st column is the status. Thank you

```
class Inventory:
def __init__(self, top=None):
    top.geometry("1366x768")
    top.resizable(0, 0)
    top.title("Inventory")

    self.userReg_Form = Label(inv)
    self.userReg_Form.place(relx=0, rely=0, width=1366, height=768)
    self.userReg_FormImage = Image.open("./images/Inventory_availability.png")
    self.userReg_FormImageResized = self.userReg_FormImage.resize((1366, 768), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.userReg_FormImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.userReg_FormImageResized)
    self.userReg_Form.configure(image=self.userReg_FormImage)

    self.scrollbarx = Scrollbar(inv, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    self.scrollbary = Scrollbar(inv, orient=VERTICAL)
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(inv)
    self.tree.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.2, width=880, height=550)
    self.tree.configure(
        yscrollcommand=self.scrollbary.set, xscrollcommand=self.scrollbarx.set
    )
    self.tree.configure(selectmode="extended")

    self.tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", self.on_tree_select)

    self.scrollbary.configure(command=self.tree.yview)
    self.scrollbarx.configure(command=self.tree.xview)

    self.scrollbary.place(relx=0.954, rely=0.203, width=22, height=548)
    self.scrollbarx.place(relx=0.307, rely=0.924, width=884, height=22)

    self.tree.configure(
        columns=(
            "Status",
            "Product ID",
            "Product_Name",
            "Quantity",
            "Supplier",
            "Price",
            "Purchase Date",
            "Expiration Date",
        )
    )

    self.tree.heading("Status", text="Status", anchor=W)
    self.tree.heading("Product ID", text="Product ID", anchor=W)
    self.tree.heading("Product_Name", text="Product_Name", anchor=W)
    self.tree.heading("Quantity", text="Quantity", anchor=W)
    self.tree.heading("Supplier", text="Supplier", anchor=W)
    self.tree.heading("Price", text="Price", anchor=W)
    self.tree.heading("Purchase Date", text="Purchase Date", anchor=W)
    self.tree.heading("Expiration Date", text="Expiration Date", anchor=W)


    self.tree.column("#0", stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=0)
    self.tree.column("#1", stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=80)
    self.tree.column("#2", stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=260)
    self.tree.column("#3", stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=100)
    self.tree.column("#4", stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=120)
    self.tree.column("#5", stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=80)
    self.tree.column("#6", stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=80)
    self.tree.column("#7", stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=80)
    self.tree.column("#8", stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=100)

    self.DisplayData()

def DisplayData(self):
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM inventory")
    fetch = cur.fetchall()
    for data in fetch:
        self.tree.insert("", "end", values=(data))

sel = []
def on_tree_select(self, Event):
    self.sel.clear()
    for i in self.tree.selection():
        if i not in self.sel:
            self.sel.append(i)
```

Below is the mySQL Create table:

```
my_cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS inventory("
                "prod_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
                "prod_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
                "quantity VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
                "supplier VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
                "price DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,"
                "purchase_date DATE NOT NULL,"
                "expiration_date DATE NOT NULL)")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

1. include status in the SQL statement:

```py
    def DisplayData(self):
        cur.execute("SELECT IF(Quantity > 0, 'available', 'out of stock'), inventory.* FROM inventory")
        fetch = cur.fetchall()
        for data in fetch:
            self.tree.insert("", "end", values=data)
```

2. prepend the status before each result record:

```py
    def DisplayData(self):
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM inventory")
        fetch = cur.fetchall()
        for data in fetch:
            self.tree.insert("", "end", values=("available" if int(data[2]) > 0 else "out of stock", *data))
```

Comment: can I add an icon instead of displaying Available and out of stock in text format? I am new in tkinter treeview. Thank you